# How to set GIF as wallpaper and stop GIF animation after some time?

Tags: java, android, animation, live-wallpaper

Is it possible to stop GIF animation and after some time start animation again? Let me explain you what exactly i am trying to do.
I want to set GIF file as wallpaper and 2 mins i want to stop the GIF animation. AND when i press the power button and unlock the device than again my GIF animation start and after 2 min it will stop.IS THIS THING IS POSSIBLE?

And what i have already DONE is i can set GIF file as wallpaper. but i cant find any way to stop that animation.So what i do is set another image as wallpaper but when i unlock the screen it will not set GIF wallpaper again and its only show old png image.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called ITTT (If this, then that). It allows you to set actions that are triggered by certain things. For example, to get the result you're looking for, you would set the action, change wallpaper to (image), with the trigger being "locking phone", and another action, change wallpaper to (GIF), wit the trigger being "unlocking phone).
The resulting effect would be that your wallpaper automatically switches between GIF and PNG when you lock/unlock your phone.